# Measure ESP8266 battery

Tags: voltage, batteries, esp8266

I am building a circuit using the ESP8266-01 and a temperature sensor. For the final test I am using a 9V battery and I have many questions:

- The 01 version only have two pins to read, but the GPIO0 should be grounded when programming, therefore how can I connect something to that pin? Putting in the code, placing in ground and then to the other sensor?
- The other question is related with measuring the battery left in the 9V battery. How can I do it?I am going to explain the situation:

The data of the sensor are uploaded to thingspeak and I though in show a webserver with the battery left, accessing through the IP of the ESP8266. Can this be done? Also I think that knowing the total voltage (9V) and the current voltage can be know the % left in the battery, isn't?

Have Anyone tried this and could share what do you think about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPIO-0 when pulled low during startup allows you to flash code in it. If GPIO-0 is HIGH during startup, it allows normal boot-up from flash. You will have to ensure that any sensor attached to it it not driving the pin LOW during a start-up sequence.

I am not sure about ESP-01 but other versions (ESP-07) has adc pin which has input range of 0-1V. You can make a voltage divider using resistors to scale your battery voltage (9V) to 1V and give that to adc pin as an input. Here is an example:

[image: esp adc ckt]

Keep the voltage divider Resistor values high because it will consume a current = Battery Voltage / Total Resistance, 0.1 mA in this case.

Comment: I have been researching and using the ESP-01 is impossible, because has not an analogue pin, so I have to upgrade to one of those versions 07,12. I will try this solution when I own the new version with analogue pin. Also this version make me easier to do the deep sleep mode. Thanks